# Loop thead if num pages more than 2 in tcpdf php

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

First, I want to tell you what project I do..
i've created exported data from database to pdf using library tcpdf php, and there is 2 table inside of them, called faktur and faktur_detail..

I have a problem with tag thead on tcpdf, because i want to loop data faktur_detail if there is more than 2 pages or more than 22 data faktur_detail join with faktur (primary), there is tag thead on pages 2 or more, its function is to facilitate users data checking faktur_detail

For more details, check a picture below

1. show pages 1 of PDF, see picture marked with circle
   [image: pages one of pdf]
2. show pages 2 or more of PDF
   [image]

If you can see, on first image show a data faktur_detail or invoice detail, with data invoice detail less than 22 or there is only on pages. And on second image, if data more than 22 or more than 2 pages will display as shown above..

Thanks for your answer..